# What is the code trick that allows photos.google.com to prevent printing of photos?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to learn how the Google Photos website is preventing printing of photo albums. I.e., when I click print in the menu while viewing an album and then try to save to PDF, the result is an empty PDF that does not show any of the thumbnails that were visible on the album page.

What is the code trick that Google is using to make this possible?

I inspected photos.google.com, and it does not seem they are using `beforeprint` or `afterprint` events, because I disabled those by pausing the devtools debugger before the first script has a chance to execute (ctrl-r immediately followed by pressing pause in the Sources panel) and then monkey patching `Window` so that `addEventListener` is a no-op for those print event names, and making `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint` properties non-writable non-configurable no-op functions. Like this:

```js
{

const original = window.addEventListener
const noprint = (event, ...args) => {
  if (['beforeprint', 'afterprint'].includes(event)) {
    debugger
    console.log('print events eliminated!')
    return
  }
  return original.call(window, event, ...args)
}
window.addEventListener = noprint
window.__proto__.addEventListener = noprint
window.onbeforeprint = () => {}
window.onafterprint = () => {}
delete window.onbeforeprint
delete window.onafterprint
delete window.__proto__.onbeforeprint
delete window.__proto__.onafterprint
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeprint', {value: () => {}, writable: false, configurable: false})
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onafterprint', {value: () => {}, writable: false, configurable: false})
Object.defineProperty(window.__proto__, 'onbeforeprint', {value: () => {}, writable: false, configurable: false})
Object.defineProperty(window.__proto__, 'onafterprint', {value: () => {}, writable: false, configurable: false})

}
```

I also disabled all `@media print` style rules in all style tags after images on the Google Photos page (f.e. in an album) have been loaded. Like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(s => s.textContent = s.textContent.replaceAll('media print', 'media foobar'))
```

However, even after doing all that, the website is still somehow able to prevent any photos from showing up in browser's print dialog (I tried both Chrome and Firefox).

It seems there is some trick that I'm not aware of. What's the trick?

Comment: Is this still true? I can print from both Chrome and Firefox on macOs

Comment: @Kaiido interesting. So when you are viewing an album, you can go to print, then save a PDF that shows all the album thumbnails (those that were loaded, as you have to scroll to make more load)?

Comment: Ah.. from the album view, no. I can't either. When viewing each photo, yes I can.

Comment: So this is not really a trick, they just did display these images as background-images, and by default your print dialog must have the "print background" option unset. Here you can see this option in my Firefox's print dialog, Chrome as a similar one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynqgr.png

Comment: @Kaiido I updated the post to reflect that about album pages.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, that was it indeed. I had no idea about that option before. Thanks! I guess the question is now invalid. On the side, it only prints one page for me; maybe that's a CSS mod needed to make it print all items beyond the first page (multiple pages).